# Implementing autofocus and opening keyboard automatically in jquery-phonegap IOS

Tags: jquery, cordova

I am implementing a very similar feature like facebook checkin in my App.
Got stuck while opening automatic keyboard and focus.

Can anyone help me out here with a more accurate solution.

Do I need to post codes also.I think its very particular problem.

Comment: can you be more elaborate ?